# ArrayOutOfBoundsException Error?

Tags: java, arrays, class, exception

I have to create classes to be implemented with the main class someone else has and for some reason I am not getting the right outputs, I'm not sure where this error is coming from.

Expected Output:

Median = 44.5

Mean = 49.300

SD = 30.581

```
public class StatPackage { 
int count; 
double [] scores; 



StatPackage() { 
count = 0; 
scores = new double[500]; 
} 
public void insert (double value) { 
if (count < 500){ 
scores[count] = value; 
++ count; 
} 
} 
public double Mean () { 
    double sum = 0; 
    //For loop for calculating average or mean
    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
            sum += (scores[i]);

    }
    double average = sum/count;  
    return average;
    } 

public double Median() { 
int min; 
int tmp; 
int size; 

for (int i = 0; i < count; i ++) 
{ 
min = i; 
for (int pos = i + 1; pos < count; pos ++) 
if (scores [pos] < scores [min]) 
min = pos; 

tmp = (int)scores [min]; 
scores [min] = scores [i]; 
scores [i] = tmp; 

} 
double median = 0;
if  (count % 2 == 0){
    median = (scores[scores.length/2-1] + scores[scores.length/2])/2;
}
else {
    median = (scores[((scores.length/2))]);
}
return median;
} 

public double Variance () { 
    double variance = 0;
    double sum = 0;
    //For loop for getting the variance
    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
        sum += scores[i];
        variance += scores[i] * scores[i];

    }
    double varianceFinal = ((variance/count)-(sum*sum)/(count*count));
    return (varianceFinal);
} 

public double StdDev (double variance) { 
    double sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
        sum += scores[i];
        variance += scores[i] * scores[i];

    }
    double varianceFinal = ((variance/count)-(sum*sum)/(count*count));
return Math.sqrt(varianceFinal);

}
```

Comment: what data are you using to get the expected results???

Comment: I'm not being lazy the error can't be seen because it is from the other code that I put my code into, I don't get the input the input is given to me by another program.

Comment: First, what outputs are you getting since it doesn't match expectations? Second, is this basically a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36389405/why-is-my-code-coming-out-with-the-wrong-output-is-my-insert-class-wrong/36389668#36389668? For my personal edification, what university is it that gave this assignment?

Comment: If the main class doesn't tell you the stack trace so you can locate a problem then it's poorly written. You have to talk to whoever wrote it and tell them to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem in your `Median()` method. Try changing

```
if  (count % 2 == 0){
    median = (scores[scores.length/2-1] + scores[scores.length/2])/2;
}
else {
    median = scores[scores.length/2];
}
```

to

```
if (count % 2 == 0)
    median = (scores[count/2] + scores[count/2 - 1])/2;
else
    median = scores[count/2];
```

Because you have a fixed-size array with 500 elements, the code you have will return the mean value of the items at position 249 and 250, which will be 0 if you have less than 251 values in your array.

Answer (score 0):

In a fit of charity/insanity, I quickly wrote a driver program to try to test this thing.

```
    public static void main(String[] args)
{
    StatsPackage sp = new StatsPackage();
    for (int i = 0; i < 101; ++i) {
        sp.insert(i);
    }

    System.out.println("count: " + sp.count);
    System.out.println("mean: " + sp.Mean());
    System.out.println("median: " + sp.Median());
    System.out.println("variance: " + sp.Variance());
}
```

Beyond the fact the median doesn't compute the right values (and @BadCash may have the solution for that problem), there is no ArrayOutOfBounds thrown.

**EDIT**: making the update as @BadCash suggested to the Median method seems to resolve the median not giving the correct answer.